# View crash log for node server running on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, node.js, crash, centos, crash-reports

My server runs on CentOS 6 and I'm using [`node supervisor`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) to run it. It crashed today and I'd like to see a log of what happened (I was ssh'd into the server in OSX terminal, it was showing nice informative logs from my node/express setup but while my laptop was asleep it crashed and I couldn't see any logs or crash information.

I'm totally new to linux/running a remote Node process, is there anywhere a log might be stored so I can see what went wrong?

Comment: Just had a quick look at the source code for supervisor (haven't used it myself). Looks like there isn't a log file written to disk so unfortunately unless you redirected the stdout to a file, don't think you'll be able to view the output from that crash. Only had a quick look though so could be wrong.

Comment: @TomGrant Interesting, thanks for taking a look. It *appears* that the entire system crashed though (at least Node/Express did, that's for sure), would there be a log file for those?

Comment: Node there won't be unless you've added some logging (such as uncaught exceptions), as for Express I honestly don't know so I can't say definitively, I've only used that for quickly prototyping basic web services, although I would imagine not unless you specify it to.